# How to restrict Backspace event for textfield in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to restrict user from removing first character in phonenumber field.  I have implemented `onKeyPress` event handler as below but it is still not restricting from removing text.

```
onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
      if (nativeEvent.key === "Backspace" && this.props.input.value.charAt(0) === '+') {
        return false
      }
    }}
```

Comment: It won't work if the user changes your first character with another one. Try removing this character from the input and concat it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function yourfunction(e) {
  if(e.code === 'Backspace' && e.target.value.charAt(0) === '+' && e.target.selectionStart<=1){ 
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault(); 
  }    
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="+915465971" onkeydown="yourfunction(event)"/>
```

I think this will work.

Comment: I don't know but `preventDefault()` generates error in react native.

Comment: can you try using setNativeProps

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want them to change it, have you considered not including it in the field?
e.g. (vanilla HTML)

```
4<input type="tel"/>
```

Where the '4' is plain text, and can't be altered.

Answer (score 0):

use onKeyDown instead of onKeyPress and if the condition passed do e.preventDefault()

Answer (score -1):

call

```
event.preventDefault()
```

where

```
onKeyPress(event) {}
```

in the function.

Don't use nativeEvent.

Comment: Not working. `nativeEvent.preventDefault()` is not a function error displays.